# Having a problem with multiple hyphens in a multistring regex match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am downloading a webpage and converting into a string using LWP::Simple. When I copy the results into an editor I find multiple instances of the pattern I'm looking for "data-src-hq".

While I'm trying to do something more complex using regex I am starting in baby steps so I can properly learn how to use regex, I started off with just to match "data-src-hq" with the following code:

```
    if($html =~ /data-src-hq/ism)
    {
      print "match\n";
    }
    else
    {
      print "nope\n";
    }
```

My code returns "nope".  However, if I modify the pattern search to just "data" or "data-src" I do get a match. The same happens no matter how I use and combine the string and multiline modifier.

My understanding is that a hyphen is not a special character unless it's within brackets, am I missing something simple?

Comment: You're missing `else`

Comment: I don't know anything about Perl syntax but any other language would crash if you're missing the `else` like that

Comment: Without the `else` that second block is just a bare block scope and runs the contained code unconditionally.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it runs as a code block because it's in `{}`. In this case, it checks the `if` statement condition, runs the code block if it evaluates to true, then, runs the next code block (bare block as @Grinnz mentioned). It's equivalent to a loop that runs once.

Comment: @Grinnz So wouldn't OP see a possible `match` followed by a guaranteed `nope`? This of course assumes that OP didn't leave out any details from their testing...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's exactly what I get when I set `$html = "data-src-hq";`

Comment: @Caractacus If you're just starting to learn regex then head over to https://regex101.com/ and test things out using the PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) option. Whatever regex you write should be directly transferable to the right side of `=~`. If you get stuck then cliick on "Code Generator" and the site will show you a sample of Perl code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Comment: Honestly that was a typo, fixed the OP

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for that site. It appears what I got from downloading the page versus viewing the source via the browser were not the exact same results.  Hence the lack of matching.  Am I able to close this question ?

Answer (score 2):

#### How to fix this?

You are likely getting two outputs, one of `match` and one of `nope`. Your code is missing the keyword `else`:

[See your code's current execution here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18loyQ3R8FWQSklsSRRt7goWTejUMmaKzNNAypTp6CPJKWfWZyryVXNpaBQUJSZV6KglJtYkpwRkwfUUoskmpdfkAoR/P8fAA)

```
if($html =~ /data-src-hq/ism)
{
  print "match\n";
}
{
  print "nope\n";
}
```

Should be:

[See this code's execution here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18loyQ3R8FWQSklsSRRt7goWTejUMmaKzNNAypTp6CPJKWfWZyryVXNpaBQUJSZV6KglJtYkpwRkwfUUquQmlOcqoAkl5dfkAqR@v8fAA)

```
if($html =~ /data-src-hq/ism)
{
  print "match\n";
}
else {
  print "nope\n";
}
```

Otherwise, your code is fine and works to identify whether `data-src-hq` exists in `$html`.

---

#### So why does your existing code output `nope`?

That's because `{}` is a basic block (see Basic BLOCKs in [Perl's documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Declarations)). An excerpt from the documentation:

> A BLOCK by itself (labeled or not) is semantically equivalent to a
>   loop that executes once. Thus you can use any of the loop control
>   statements in it to leave or restart the block. (Note that this is NOT
>   true in `eval{}`, `sub{}`, or contrary to popular belief `do{}` blocks,
>   which do NOT count as loops.) The `continue` block is optional.